# Turn off iOS Camera Night Mode by default?

Tags: iphone, ios, settings, camera

iOS Camera added the impressive Night Mode in iOS 13 on the iPhone 11:

> #### Take low-light photos with Night mode
>
> Night mode automatically turns on when the camera detects a low-light environment.
>
> https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211306

However, I really don't like how Night Mode prevents Live Photos from being shot. It's also much slower at shooting, and messes with photos you intend to be dark.

I'd still like to use Night Mode, sometimes, but want to turn it on manually. But the Camera app defaults to Night Mode every time I open it in the dark... I need to spend 2-5 seconds manually turning it off.

How can I turn off Night Mode permanently, and only toggle it on manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not possible in iOS 13 or iOS 14. Night Mode would turn on automatically in the dark.

In **iOS 15** in 2021, there is a new setting to control Night Mode:

> Settings > Camera > Preserve Settings > Night Mode

Toggle the switch to **On**:

> #### Night Mode
>
> Preserve the Night mode setting, rather than automatically reset Night mode to Auto.

Then, when you turn **Off** Night Mode once in the Camera app, it should stay off until you manually turn the mode back on.

---

[image: Settings > Camera > Preserve Settings > Night Mode]